# Which branch to traverse next in a cyclic directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, traversal, directed-graph, continuous

I have a cyclic directed graph that let's assume water flows between the vertices back to the starting node in a continues loop, if I have a node with 3 branches going out of that node and meeting at a later node does it matter if I visit any of the branches first or should I visit the 3 branches at the same time using BFS ?

I am still trying to figure out what graph traversal method to use or does it even matter or not.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Have you implemented a traversal method, tried it, and looked at the result?

Comment: I am trying to simulate a closed loop graph and calculate the output (sum of values inside each node) I didn't implement a traversal method yet, the question is will it differ in the output after each cyclic walk whether I use DFS or BFS ?

Comment: You should try both and see if there is any difference.  Neither search is hard to code, or you could use a graph theory library when the work becomes trivial.  This approach will be faster and more effective than wondering and asking and wondering...  If you have problems with your implementation, THEN would be a good time to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

A **depth first** path can detect a cycle by checking that the next node is already on the path. *Properties: single path, quadratic complexity.*

A **bread first** search however can find the shortest path, as all paths of the same length are lengthened by 1. *Properties: bulk marking, multiple nodes.*

Many algorithms use BFS in some form (not only for graphs), forming an ever expanding border, to optimize, find minimal paths.

*As you mention a number of outputs.* In a directed graph an odd number of edges means either an *source* (start) or *sink* (end) ideally (nunber of inputs and number of outputs differ by 1). This sometimes is relevant: from ... to ... .

If you have a graph of 10,000 nodes DFS could take a very long time, even if the cycle is just 5 nodes long. So BFS seems faster.
However you will need marking nodes, set operations or such.

I have no conclusive answer.

Comment: thank you for your effort but that's not close to my question my question is that I am trying to simulate a closed loop graph and calculate the output (sum of values inside each node) will it differ in the output after each cyclic walk whether I use DFS or BFS ?